# How to deploy a local eclipse worklight project in cloud server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I developed an android based hybrid app in the IBM MFP-7.0., My app is fetching the data from the Java service which is running in Tomcat Server. Here the app adapters are running in my local system MFP server to get the data from the Java service, So that I can only run the app in my local system android emulator. Now, we want to deploy the app in the cloud so that we can give this app to our users. Can some body help me how to run our MFP app in the cloud? Is it required to place eclipse in the cloud to run my MFP server like the way I am running in my local system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your understanding is completely lacking in this subject matter. Also note that this question has got nothing to do with *programming*.

- You need a host machine. On this server you will run an application server (Tomcat, WebSphere Full profile, WebSphere Liberty profile - either single or a farm, depending on your required network topology and security & scalability needs).
- On this application server you deploy MobileFirst
- You will also need a database
- This host machine needs to be accessible (with appropriate security) to the public Internet so that it could serve apps installed in end-users' devices
- The application needs to be configured to send requests to the server (or to any front-side server like a Load Balancer, again, depending on your topology)
- The generated application needs to be submitted to an App Store so that users could download and install it on their devices

I suggest that you will do some reading before asking any question. Since you're using IBM MobileFirst, start by reading the user documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html